# Escape from chain of Assigned() in Delphi

Tags: object, delphi, null

Sometimes I see in source code long chain of checks by Assigned() in deep of object like

```
if Assigned (ASomeObj)
   and Assigned (ASomeObj.Session)
   and Assigned (ASomeObj.Session.UserInfo)
   and Assigned (ASomeObj.Session.UserInfo.SomeFactsList)
then
  // to do some actions
```

It's the way to check by **nil** all intermediate entities. Maybe anybody knows a way to cropping chain in condition part?

As an idea a watched to

```
try
  if Assigned (ASomeObj.Session.UserInfo.SomeFactsList)
  then
    // to do some actions
except

end;
```

Whether exists paths to simplify it?
How it is clear and easy for reading source code?

As I know in Csharp exist "?" operator for using like *ASomeObj?.Session?.UserInfo?.SomeFactsList* for check by **Null**

Comment: Shouldn't you call a method on `ASomeObj` that would delegate to `Session` if `Session` were assigned, and then in turn `Session` calls a method that delegates to `UserInfo` if `UserInfo` were assigned, etc. `foo.bar.foobar.boofar.etc` is a bit of a code smell tbh

Comment: David, why you think that stack of calls inside (in deep objects) is better that Assigned()?
Assigned() will be launched at the origin code level. Many calls will redirect you to another level. Just now I don't see the positive side in this way. But I can wrong.
And how to be if it not the method but path to property?

Comment: The reason is that `foo.bar.foobar.boofar.etc` introduces deep coupling between all of these classes. If you change the name of `boofar`, for instance, that permeates up to `foobar`, but also up to `bar` and `foo`. However, if you did it the way I said, the scope of the change is much reduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR There's no such operator in Delphi language and I don't think we'll get it anytime soon. But there are some good practices as a way around it. Read more ...

Let's start from the bottom of your question.

> As I know in CSharp exist `?` operator for using like
>   `ASomeObj?.Session?.UserInfo?.SomeFactsList` for check by `null`

First of all there is no `?` operator in C#, but there are some that have `?` in them:

- `?:` [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)
- `??` (C# 2+) [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)
- `?.` and `?[]` (both C# 6+) [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)
- `??=` (C# 8+) [null-coalescing assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

You were obviously referring to `?.` a.k.a. [safe navigation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator) or even

[image: Elvis operator]

There's no such operator in Delphi language and I don't think we'll get it anytime soon considering that there's not even true ternary conditional operator yet:

- [RSP-12100](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12100): Add a ternary operator to the Delphi language
- [RSP-14621](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14621): Proposed syntax for ternary operator

You're not the only one asking for it - there's an open feature request to [add support for null-conditional operator (RSP-21323)](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21323).

FWIW: Oxygene language from RemObjects Software (disclaimer: no relation) has [colon operator](https://www.elementscompiler.com/elements/oxygene/language.aspx#colonoperator) for this purpose.

Where do we go from here? I would first recommend you to re-think your design (as it was pointed out by the comments under the question).

Let me quote from [Just Say No to Nulls (or Refactoring Your Way to Programmer Bliss)](https://hackerchick.com/just-say-no-to-nulls-or-refactoring/):

> The truth is, when we find ourselves wading through endless object hierarchies such as these, that there is what we call a code smell. And it’s a pretty good indication that we might want to revisit our design. A true OO design is composed of nice little well behaved classes that expose methods we can call on to have them do things for us. These classes abstract the nitty gritty behind the scenes details and just do it (often without the need to return any value at all).
>
> `dog.bark()` not `dog.getAnatomy().getVoiceBox().EmitSound("woof")`

Another option would be to make the intermediate objects not `nil` using [Null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). That would help you get rid of chained `Assigned` checks.

Cheap and dirty solution would be to introduce shorthand property `SomeFactsList` or class helper directly on `ASomeObj` so at least you wouldn't need to repeat yourself all over the place, if you have.

Further reading:

- [Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare/)
- [Unhealthy Code: Null Checks Everywhere!](https://dev.to/jamesmh/unhealthy-code-null-checks-everywhere-2720)

Comment: "*Cheap and dirty solution would be to introduce shorthand property `SomeFactsList` or class helper directly on `ASomeObj`*" - for example, Indy's `TIdContext` has a shorthand `Binding` property that returns `TIdContext.Connection.Socket.Binding`, doing all of the `nil` checks in the property getter. That way, code could do `Binding := AContext.Binding; if Assigned(Binding) then Binding.DoSomething;` instead of doing `if Assigned(AContext.Connection) and Assigned(AContext.Connection.Socket) and Assigned(AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding) then AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.DoSomething;`

Comment: It is not a general rule that should be blindly applied. Sometimes there's a good reason (performance, code complexity, ...) to have such constructs in the code. On the other hand that doesn't imply that such a design can't be improved. I admit you can find some of that in my code, so I might not have the right to point the finger ;)